# CSS attribute selector does not work a href

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to use attribute selector in css to change link on different color and image, but it does not work.

I have this html:

```
<a href="/manual.pdf">A PDF File</a>
```

And this css:

```
a {
     display: block;
     height: 25px;
     padding-left: 25px;
     color:#333;
     font: bold 15px Tahoma;
     text-decoration: none;
 }
 a[href='.pdf'] { background: red; }
```

Why isn't the background red?

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about a[attribute='AttributeName']

Comment: @SpaceBeers, that's `element[attribute_name="attribute_value"]`.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Use the $ after your href. This will make the attribute value to match the end of the string.

```
a[href$='.pdf'] { /*css*/ }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UG9ud/

```
E[foo]        an E element with a "foo" attribute (CSS 2)
E[foo="bar"]  an E element whose "foo" attribute value is exactly equal to "bar" (CSS 2)
E[foo~="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar" (CSS 2)
E[foo^="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar" (CSS 3)
E[foo$="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar" (CSS 3)
E[foo*="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar" (CSS 3)
E[foo|="en"]  an E element whose "foo" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "en" (CSS 2)
```

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/

Comment: Attribute value to match the end of the string. sounds like a bonus!!

Comment: This answer has better explanations of the selectors than w3schools.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer (using `a[href$='.pdf']`) assumes that that a link to a pdf will always end with `.pdf`. That is not necessarily the case, as the link could have a query string or a hash fragment, for example with a UTM tracking code or a page number, in which case those links would not be matched. In fact depending on your application this could be the case for most links.

```
<a href="/manual.pdf?utm_source=homepage">A PDF File</a>
<a href="/manual.pdf#page=42">A PDF File</a>
```

If you want to ensure your rule is also applied in those cases you could match `.pdf` anywhere in the attribute using

```
a[href*='.pdf']
```

However this will then match some unlikely but unintended things, such as  a subdomain `our.pdf.domain.com/a-page`. But we can narrow it down further, as we know we would only use it match pdfs that have a query string or hash fragment. If we combine the 3 cases we should match all pdf links.

```
a[href$='.pdf'], a[href*='.pdf?'], a[href*='.pdf#'] {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should also work:

```
a[href*='.pdf'] { background: red; }
```

Comment: I see no reason to repeat other answers.