# Style anchor by href

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a dynamically added anchors.

html:

```
<ul role="menu" aria-label="Pagination">
    <li><a href="#previous" role="menuitem">previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#next" role="menuitem">nextstep</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
a[href^='next']{display: none;}
```

and like this:

```
a[href='next']{display: none;}
```

But none of them worked and I didn't find anything useful on google.

I can't use CSS3 on this project like `child` and I wouldn't like to use javascript to solve this problem neither.

Is there a simple CSS solution for this problem? Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: *I wouldn't like to use javascript to solve this problem neither.* Any particular reason why?

Comment: How are they generated dynamically? Is it possible for you to add classes previous and next to the anchors?

Comment: I believe that there is no easy solution.  Consider adding either a class or an id when you add the anchor and style by that.

Comment: This might be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850173/css-attribute-selector-does-not-work-a-href][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850173/css-attribute-selector-does-not-work-a-href

Comment: @esqew I wouldn't like to use javascript to solve this problem because it's not necessary, in fact someone show me that it's possible to solve it using only CSS

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos fair enough. Just surprised to see the aversion to Javascript even before knowing it could be completed in pure CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `#` character:

```css
a[href^='#next'] { display: none; }
```

This particular selector would also match things like `#next1234` as `^=` matches text from the start of the attribute. If you want to match *only* `"#next"` you'll want to just use:

```css
a[href='#next'] { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/rnZWK/)**

Using css attribute selector

```
a[href="#previous"] {
    color: green;
}
a[href="#next"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Few example here in detail

```
a[href*="#next"] /* attribute containing #next somewhere */
a[href^="#next"] /* attribute begins with #next */
a[href$="#next"] /* attribute ends with #next */
a[href~="#next"] /* #next is space separated in attribute */
a[href~="#next"] /* #next is dash separated in attribute */
```

[Read this for more information](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want

```
a[href="#next"] { display:none; }
```