# CSS: Refer to link item by it's target url/href

Tags: css, url

I'm looking for a way to refer to a link by it's target URL. I can't change the HTML to give the links unique names or such.
So basically something like:

```
a whereTargetURL="/Destination"
{
styling
}
```

Comment: Please see [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8850186/2844093).

Comment: Thanks Eliot. Couldn't find the right words while searching the answer for this.

Comment: You're welcome :) Also, if you're curious about CSS selectors, you should have a look at [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can proceed like that: http://jsfiddle.net/4F83h/

**HTML** `<a href="demo.html">My link</a>`

**CSS**

```
a[href="demo.html"]{
    /*your rules*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the attribute selector:

```
a[href="Destination"]
{
  styling
}
```