# css attribute selectors not working

Tags: php, html, css, css-selectors

I have some PHP code that generates a bunch of items like this:

```
<a href="page.php?day=1&month=1&year=2017"><li>item 1</li></a>
```

Now I'm trying to select some of them with CSS based on their `day=` value to give them different styling.

So I tried this CSS code:

```
a[href*="day=1"] { background-color: grey; }
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8850186/3863006) answer from another post. But it's not doing anything even though it works in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UG9ud/) (also from that other post).

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Edit: My actual code obviously does have an  element around the `<a><li></li></a>` elements. The problem is my css doesn't seem to reach my elements. Because when I inspect the an element that should be affected with chrome developer tools it's not showing any trace of the css. I'm thinking it's somehow related to it being php generated

Comment: It is probably a better idea to use the php add a class to the <a> tag instead of using a css selector like this

Comment: I normally would do that but in this case the list is called through a function ( $list = new List(); echo $list->show(); ) and I don't want to touch the code in that class. + I am curious to know why this isn't working

Comment: You can't put an li as a direct child of an anchor but your selector works - your anchor has day=1, your selector is for day=2: http://jsfiddle.net/UG9ud/211/

Comment: change `[href*="day=1"]` into `[href*="day=2"]`? or have you noticed you're using day 2 instead of day 1

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius Ah, no I'm sorry this is just as an example. In my actual code all the day values do match

Comment: @Pete I know I accidentally mismatched them in my question here but that's not the case in my actual code. The thing is my rule does work in the fiddle but is just not showing up at all in my actual project. There's no trace of it when I inspect the elements that should be affected

Comment: there is no problem with your code. there can be only problem with your browser

Comment: You must either have a parse error in your actual code then causing the selector not be be read or there is some other error.  Can you create a fiddle with your rendered code and all the styles from your stylesheet.  It is hard to diagnose a problem when you haven't recreated it - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Also have you tried fixing your html so it is valid - some browsers will automatically fix it and that will cause issues with the rendering of classes as the structure will have changed

Comment: Look but the code is not working even when I add it directly through developer tools: [it's light grey](http://i.imgur.com/kQtXxnG.png) for some reason

Comment: **Your mark-up is invalid. An li cannot be a child of an anchor element. Only ul, ol and menu can be parents**

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is working fine.

The problem is you've put a *block-level* element inside an *inline-level* element.

This causes the browser to close the anchor element before the list item. As a result, the anchor and list item, originally parent and child, are now siblings (spec details below).

Because the anchor is now an empty box with no width, the background color cannot be seen.

Add `display: block` or `inline-block` to the anchor.

```css
[href*="day=1"] { background-color: aqua; display: block; }
```

```html
<a href="page.php?day=1&month=1&year=2017">
  <li>item 1</li>
</a>
```

Of course, your mark-up is invalid. An `li` cannot be a child of an anchor element. Only `ul`, `ol` and `menu` can be parents. Consider this instead:

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
a[href*="day=1"] {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="page.php?day=1&month=1&year=2017">item 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

*From the spec:*

Browser behavior when an inline-level element contains a block-level element.

> [**9.2.1.1 Anonymous block
>   boxes**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level)
>
> When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box
>   (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) is broken around
>   the block-level box (and any block-level siblings that are consecutive
>   or separated only by collapsible whitespace and/or out-of-flow
>   elements), splitting the inline box into two boxes (even if either
>   side is empty), one on each side of the block-level box(es). The line
>   boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous
>   block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those
>   anonymous boxes. When such an inline box is affected by relative
>   positioning, any resulting translation also affects the block-level
>   box contained in the inline box.