# Part of jQuery code is not working with .ejs file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I am using `.ejs` with `nodeJS`.
**Part** of my `jQuery` code is not working. As well, it **does not throw any errors in console.**

`jQuery` is connected to `index.ejs` in the end of the document like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

By clicking here:

```
<ul class="nav__right">
     <li class="nav__link" id="delivery-link">Доставка</li>
     <li class="nav__link nav__link-ml" id="firms-link">Фирмам</li>
     <li class="nav__link nav__link-ml" id="contacts-link">Контакты</li>
</ul>
```

I wish to slide down to blocks which have **id's** as well.

`jQuery` code looks like this:

```
$("#logo-link").click(function() {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
}); // This part is working!

$("#about-link").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top-navHeight},
        'slow');
});

$("#products-link").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#products").offset().top-navHeight},
        'slow');
});

$("#find-link").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#find").offset().top-navHeight},
        'slow');
});
```

Part which goes to top is working, **other are not working**.
I have tested the same code with basic .html file and it works perfectly.
I guess, issue appeared due to `.ejs`, however, absolutely cannot figure this out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the click event listeners firing?

Comment: Yes, they work.

Comment: Hard to help then without a [mre] that demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
//Smooth scrolling with links
$('a[href*=\\#]').on('click', function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
});

// Smooth scrolling when the document is loaded and ready
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(location.hash).offset().‌​top}, 500);
});
```

**Simplifying**: DRY

```
function smoothScrollingTo(target){
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(target).offset().​top}, 500);
}
$('a[href*=\\#]').on('click', function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    smoothScrollingTo(this.hash);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  smoothScrollingTo(location.hash);
});
```

Explanation of `href*=\\#`:

- `*` means it matches what contains `#` char. Thus only match *anchors*. For more about the meaning of this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8850186/4619958)
- `\\` is because the `#` is a special char in css selector, so we have to escape it.